# проблемы с командой приветствия дискорд.ру

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

````
async def on_member_join(member):
    chanel = bot.get_channel(a)
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} присоиединился')
@bot.command()
async def setchanel(ctx,*,chanel):
    setchanel = chanel
    return setchanel```

я хочу чтобы через команду setchanel можно было задать айди канала, в который будут приходить сообщения о заходе участников. но выдает ошибку. помогите пожалуйста
````

Comment: У вас функция `setchanel` первой же строкой перезаписывает себя на объект канала (`discord.Channel`) и после этого больше не будет работать, так как функции по факту больше не будет существовать (`setchanel` теперь канал, а не функция). Куда по вашему мнению возвращается канал через`return`?

Comment: понял. есть ли замена return в данной функции? если да, и если вам не сложно то киньте пожалуйста готовый код. сейчас попробую поменять название переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не применял id канала..

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global chanel
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} присоединился')

@bot.command()
async def setchanel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel)
    global chanel
    chanel = channel
```

А здесь уже с применением id

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global chanel
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} присоединился')

@bot.command()
async def setchanel(ctx, channel_id)
    global chanel
    chanel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ваш ответ!

Comment: Был был благодарен, если бы вы приняли мой ответ(галочка слева от текста)

Comment: line 69, in on_member_remove
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} вышел')
NameError: name 'chanel' is not defined

Comment: вылез вот такой бред(remove сделан так же как и join по вашему коду). с join так же