# проблемы с командой приветствия участников

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global chanel
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} присоединился')

@bot.command()
async def setchanel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    chanel = channel
```

я хочу чтобы команда setchanel могла задать канал для отправки сообщения, когда заходит пользователь. выдает следующую ошибку:

```
line 58, in on_member_join
    await chanel.send(f'{member.name} присоединился')
NameError: name 'chanel' is not defined
```

Comment: В функции `setchanel` добавьте в начало строку `global chanel`

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В команде `setchanel` добавьте `global chanel`.
Я уже вроде отвечал вам в этой теме [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410952/проблемы-с-командой-приветствия-дискорд-ру/1410956#1410956](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410952/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D1%80%D1%83/1410956#1410956)